# Why can not modify a map in foreach?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala and use Spark to process data. Why does the following code fail to change the categoryMap?

```
 import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap
 val catFile=sc.textFile(inputFile);
 var categoryMap=LinkedHashMap[Int,Tuple2[String,Int]]()
 catFile.foreach(line => {
     val strs=line.split("\001");
     categoryMap += (strs(0).toInt -> (strs(2),strs(3).toInt));
 })
```

Comment: It works for me https://gist.github.com/alexandrnikitin/29e82b1a042895671e23

Comment: Note that you are splitting on a String, which is being interpreted as a regular expression.  Splitting on a char is faster.  And if you really want to split on a regex, it's better to compile it first.

Answer (score 4):

It's a good practice to try to stay away from both mutable data structures and vars. Sometimes they are needed, but mostly this kind of processing is easy to do by chaining transformation operations on collections. Also, `.toMap` is handy to convert a `Seq` containing `Tuple2`'s to a `Map`.

Here's one way (that I didn't test properly):

```
val categoryMap = catFile map { _.split("\001") } map { array =>
  (array(0).toInt, (array(2), array(3).toInt))
} toMap
```

Note that if there are more than one record corresponding to a key then only the last one will be present in the resulting map.

**Edit:** I didn't actually answer your original question - based on a quick test it results in a similar map to what my code above produces. Blind guess, you should make sure that your `catFile` actually contains data to process.